# MySQL database can not be restored by copying the database folder into data folder

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to restore `MySQL` database from a folder with `frm`, `MYD`, `MYI` files.

As my partner shown (remotely) that it works only copying the database folder into `data` folder under `mysql` installation path, for me it's `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server5.5\data`.

I found some answers here saying the same way doing this. But it didn't work for me. Did I miss something?

I tried restart the `MySQL service`, still got no luck.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_Name LIKE "%dir"'

what do you get when you run this?

Comment: You want the `datadir`? It's correct as I mentioned.

Comment: If this is a new database you need to tell MySQL about it. Just dumping files into a directory doesn't do that. You need to CREATE DATABASE and define all the tables. You should really be doing this via `mysqldump.`

Comment: Can `mysqldump` restore database from `frm`, `myd` and `myi` files?

Comment: @Sky `mysqldump` restores your database completely, everything from frm, myd, and myi files. Go ahead and restore it buddy :)

Comment: @ShivaShinde Can you show me how to restore it with `mysqldump`? I just didn't find any doc or online info about this.

Comment: @Sky I am assuming that you are using Windows, so hope this tutorial helps [mysqldump](https://john-dugan.com/dump-and-restore-mysql-databases-in-windows/)

Comment: @Sky Its actually simple, log into your mysql on any machine, and then exit out of mysql. Then run mysqldump command which I pasted below and check the file in a folder where ever you have ran the command. Let me know If you need more help, https://john-dugan.com/dump-and-restore-mysql-databases-in-windows/, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks. But I see that it's restored from sql file in your tutorial.

Comment: Did I misunderstand you? I add a solution which works for me. All I have is a folder with `.frm`, `.myd` and `.myi` files, no sql file contained. Can it be restored using `mysqldump`?

Comment: @sky Seems like you found the problem. You should find the file with whatever extension (.sql in this case), you have saved it. When you restore a file using `mysqldump`, you should find that file in what ever folder you have ran the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured that I should use the same version of `MySQL` as my parter's.

I also encountered a problem is that the data folder is different after I installed the version 5.7.x, it's `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data` for my environment, which is a hidden folder by default. It can be changed in `my.ini` with `datadir` as its key.

Comment: So what was the output of:
 
'SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_Name LIKE "%dir"'

Comment: Wha do you mean? Lots of `*dir`s, which one do you want to know?

Comment: so the data directory was different to what you stated in your question.

Comment: I see. But this is not the problem, the directory stated in my question is the folder for `MySQL 5.5`, later I changed it to `5.7`, so the folder changes, which is the default one. And it can be modified in `my.ini`.

Answer (score 1):

This could be possible because of some permissions problem, do you have access to those folders in which mysql .frm, MYD, MYI files are located?

And also there is a better way to restore your database, this is more popular and preferred one.

```
mysqldump --single-transaction databasename > database.sql
```

You can also dump the database in a particular folder

```
mysqldump --single-transaction dumptest > ~/database.sql
```

If you are specific about copying folders, please follow the steps by Rolando on a windows machine, [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/111829/changing-data-directory-on-mysql-db-server)

Comment: I think so. I logged in as administrator, and the default db here is shown correctly.

Comment: As I have commented above, I would suggest you to restore your database using mysqldump, it is the best way, it will restore all your files mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

if you have the apache installed, you could consult the database in php myadmin. It worked once for me. Then you can copy the files to a folder and import it to mysql workbench or whatever you use.

Give it a try if the database was originally in your computer.

Comment: Thanks. But I only got the files with this format, so I need to restore it in this way. No sql file.